Custom Magento form redirecting to homepage unless there is a breakpoint in Magento Generated client.js in Safari
I have an issue that has been confounding me.  I recently upgraded Magento from 2.4.3 to 2.4.6.  I have a custom form that since then has been redirecting to the home page rather than submitting, but only in Safari. I ruled out CSP issues, Form Key issues, and have no errors in the console. I discovered that if I put a breakpoint in the _save function in client.js (which is a file generated by Magento) the form operates correctly.  This leads me to believe it is a timing issue, but since it is generated and handled by Magento I am not sure how to fix it.
The code is below:
Magento's client.js
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mageUtils',
    'uiClass'
], function ($, _, utils, Class) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * Before save validate request.
     *
     * @param {Object} data
     * @param {String} url
     * @param {String} selectorPrefix
     * @param {String} messagesClass
     * @returns {*}
     */
    function beforeSave(data, url, selectorPrefix, messagesClass) {
        var save = $.Deferred();

        data = utils.serialize(utils.filterFormData(data));
        data['form_key'] = window.FORM_KEY;

        if (!url || url === 'undefined') {
            return save.resolve();
        }

        $('body').trigger('processStart');

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,

            /**
             * Success callback.
             * @param {Object} resp
             * @returns {Boolean}
             */
            success: function (resp) {
                if (!resp.error) {
                    save.resolve();

                    return true;
                }

                $('body').notification('clear');
                $.each(resp.messages || [resp.message] || [], function (key, message) {
                    $('body').notification('add', {
                        error: resp.error,
                        message: message,

                        /**
                         * Insert method.
                         *
                         * @param {String} msg
                         */
                        insertMethod: function (msg) {
                            var $wrapper = $('<div></div>').addClass(messagesClass).html(msg);

                            $('.page-main-actions', selectorPrefix).after($wrapper);
                            $('html, body').animate({
                                scrollTop: $('.page-main-actions', selectorPrefix).offset().top
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            },

            /**
             * Complete callback.
             */
            complete: function () {
                $('body').trigger('processStop');
            }
        });

        return save.promise();
    }

    return Class.extend({

        /**
         * Assembles data and submits it using 'utils.submit' method
         */
        save: function (data, options) {
            var url = this.urls.beforeSave,
                save = this._save.bind(this, data, options);

            beforeSave(data, url, this.selectorPrefix, this.messagesClass).then(save);

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Save data.
         *
         * @param {Object} data
         * @param {Object} options
         * @returns {Object}
         * @private
         */
        _save: function (data, options) {
            var url = this.urls.save;

            $('body').trigger('processStart');
            options = options || {};

            if (!options.redirect) {
                url += 'back/edit';
            }

            if (options.ajaxSave) {
                utils.ajaxSubmit({
                    url: url,
                    data: data
                }, options);

                $('body').trigger('processStop');

                return this;
            }

            utils.submit({
                url: url,
                data: data
            }, options.attributes);

            return this;
        }
    });
});

RecurringService/view/frontend/templates/pageactions.phtml
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

use RecurringService\ViewModel\FormKey;

/** @var FormKey $viewModel */
$viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
?>

<?php if ($block->getChildHtml()) : ?>
    <script>
        var FORM_KEY = '<?= /* @noEscape */ $viewModel->getFormKey() ?>';
    </script>
    <div>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

RecurringService/view/frontend/layout/recurring_schedule_index.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">My Service Schedule</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="service_schedule_description">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">service-schedule-description</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <uiComponent name="service_schedule_form"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                   cacheable="false"
                   name="page.actions.toolbar" template="RecurringService::pageactions.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">RecurringService\ViewModel\FormKey</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>

RecurringService/view/frontend/ui_component/service_schedule_form.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">service_schedule_form.service_schedule_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="save" class="RecurringService\Block\ServiceSchedule\Form\SaveButton"/>
        </buttons>
        <namespace>service_schedule_form</namespace>
        <dataScope>data</dataScope>
        <deps>
            <dep>service_schedule_form.service_schedule_form_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="service_schedule_form_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <submitUrl path="recurring/schedule/save"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="RecurringService\Model\RecurringProfile\DataProvider"
                      name="service_schedule_form_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>profile_id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>entity_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="service_schedule" class="RecurringService\Ui\Component\Form\ServiceSchedule">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Service Schedule</label>
        </settings>
    </fieldset>
</form>

RecurringService/Block/ServiceSchedule/Form/SaveButton.php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace RecurringService\Block\ServiceSchedule\Form;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

/**
 * Class SaveButton
 */
class SaveButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * Gets button data
     *
     * @return mixed[]
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label'          => __('Update Service Schedule'),
            'class'          => 'save primary',
            'data_attribute' => [
                'mage-init' => [
                    'buttonAdapter' => [
                        'actions' => [
                            [
                                'targetName' => 'service_schedule_form.service_schedule_form',
                                'actionName' => 'save'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }
}

